# How to query in Datastax DSE Graph having year as partition key

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am following schema given in this [link](http://www.beyondthelines.net/databases/dsegraph-under-the-hood/), excluding all the vertex indexes given in it.

Creating vertex label movie as

```
schema.vertexLabel("movie").partitionKey("year").clusteringKey("title").create();
```

Sample Id created by DSE "{~label=movie, year=2009, title=Movie1}"

I want to get all the movies of a particular year say 2009 only

What query should I write on gremlin console?

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the article...

"Now all the movies that were released on the same year will occupy the same partition."

`g.V().hasId("{~label: movie, year: 2010}");`

"This snippet gives us all the movies releases in 2010, reading only a single partition."